# Array manipulaion using lookup values in numpy

Tags: numpy

```
lookup = np.array([60, 40, 50, 70, 90])

a = np.array([1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 9, 1])
b = np.array([2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1])
c = np.array([4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 9])
```

The following array values correspond to the following lookup values:

```
1 --> 60
2 --> 40
3 --> 50
4 --> 70
9 --> 90
```

This is what I have to do

```
array       1st column elements             lookup value

a            1        -->                   60
b            2        -->                   40
c            4        -->                   70
```

Maximum is 70.

So, first element of result is 4.

This way,

expected result = array([4, 1, ...., 9])

What would be better way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: What is the expected result? How do you obtain it? Do you have to sort values or what.

Comment: @Ardweaden In the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182550) and an in the meantime deleted question, there was something mentioned with maximum, but all questions remain unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have custom indices here, so you need to set up a dictionary to substitute your custom indices with the lookup values, like so:

```py
index_map = { 1: 60, 2: 40, 3: 50, 4: 70, 9: 90 }
```

Then, we create a temporary NumPy array with the actual `lookup` values for the indices from `d`:

```py
temp = np.array([index_map[int(x)] for x in np.nditer(d)]).reshape(d.shape)
```

So, we can then re-use [this valid answer on your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182616/11089932) (option 1):

```py
rows = temp.argmax(0)
print(d[rows, np.arange(d.shape[1])])
```

Output:

```
[4 1 1 4 4 4 9 9 9]
```